# Jshelper cakephp is not getting data from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, post

I have this simple html code:

```
<nav class="submenu">
<ul id="typesPools" class="menu">
    <li class="active type" id="active"><a href="#">Presidente</a></li>
    <li class="type"><a href="#">Governador</a></li>
    <li class="type"><a href="#">Senador</a></li>
    <li class="type"><a href="#">Deputado Federal</a></li>
    <li class="type"><a href="#">Deputado Estadual</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I'm trying to create a Js request if a user clicks on any element of the active class, a js post request will be send to some controller with the text present in the link of it, and this case the word "Presidente". My Jshelper is as follows:

```
    <?php
    $this->Js->get('.type')->event(
        'click',
        $this->Js->request(
            array(
                'controller'=>'votes',
                'action'=>'changeMenuVotation'
            ),
            array(
                'update'=>'#typesPools',
                'async' => true,
                'method' => 'post',
                'dataExpression'=>true,
                'data'=> '$("#active a").serialize()'
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

The js post is working, but the data that need to be send is not being captured.
Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serialize()` is ment to serialize form elements, it wont get you anything on other elements. You should use `text()` instead.

For more information see

- **http://api.jquery.com/serialize/**
- **http://api.jquery.com/text/**

On a side note, the JS helper is deprecated, it's recommended to use raw JavaScript instead.